# Shortest path algorithm that passes through at least one of a particular type of vertex

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I have a graph with about 6500 vertices, some of which have the label 'c'. I need to devise an algorithm that finds the shortest path between any two of the vertices that includes AT LEAST ONE of these 'c' vertices. This is simple enough, but the problem is that the required complexity is O(ElogV) where E is the number of edges, and V is the number of vertices. I have already implemented Dijkstra's Algorithm using a min-heap, so I can find the general shortest path in O(ElogV), but I am having trouble extending the problem. Any suggestions?

Note that calling Dijkstra's from source to c + c to destination iteratively does not fall within the complexity restraints, as it ends up being O(CElogV)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the failed approach in my 'note' was as far as I got :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let G be your graph, with vertices v1...vn.

Make a new graph that consists of two copies of your original vertices: v1..vn, v1'..vn'. In this new graph, let there be an edge between vi and vj or vi' and vj' if there's an edge between vi and vj in your original graph. Also let there be an edge between vi and vj' if there's an edge between vi and vj in your original graph, and vj' is labelled c.

Then, given two vertices vi, vj, the shortest path between vi and vj' in the new graph is the shortest path between vi and vj in the original graph that passes through at least one vertex labelled c.

Because the number of vertices in the new graph is doubled, and the number of edges at most tripled, the complexity doesn't change from O(VlogE) (where V and E are the number of vertices/edges in the original graph).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I'm currently implementing it to see how I go

Comment: Update- I've implemented it and it works like a charm! Absolutely stoked, I don't think I could have ever come up with that idea on my own. Thanks heaps, mate

Comment: Hey how to you solve the problem when we have a subset S of the vertex set V and we want all shortest paths from source to destination to pass through a vertex in S at least every 3 edges?

Comment: @PaulHankin isn't this O(ElogV) instead of your suggested answer O(VlogE)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an undirected graph:

Say you're searching for a shortest path between S and T.

- find all the shortest paths from S to any node using Dijkstra's algorithm
- find all the shortest paths from T to any node (same algorithm)
- iterate over all marked nodes c and find the shortest path *S to c combined with c to T* using previously calculated shortest paths.